# fix error variable referenced before assignment in python and streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, function, pyodbc, streamlit

i have a python project where i try to connect to SQL database and having function that style the dataframe based on the returned results.

Them problem is that once i run the code it crash and display the below error:

> NameError: free variable 'color' referenced before assignment in
> enclosing scope

## code:

```
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import streamlit as st



@st.experimental_singleton
def connect_db():
   con = pyodbc.connect(
   driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
   Server = "192.168.21.132",
        
   DATABASE="tasks",
   UID="xxxx",
   PWD="xxxx",
   )
   cursor = con.cursor()
   return con


def highlight_rows(row):
    value = row.loc["status_type"]
    if value == "done":
        color = "#ffffff"
    elif value == "pending":
        color = "#474d51"
    return [f'background-color: {color}' for _ in row]


con = connect_db()
df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from tasks.dbo.info',con)
st.dataframe(df.reset_index(drop=True).style.apply(highlight_rows,axis = 1),height = 500)
```

Comment: Do you have cases where the value of `value` could be anything other than `"done"` or `"pending"`?

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine yes the values of the column `status_type` are **done** and **pending**

Comment: try enclosing the function body in a `try` , `except` block and printing the `value` when an error is caught

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you did not specify a condition where the value of `value` could be anything other than `"done"` or `"pending"`.

It can be avoided by having an `else` clause inside your function `highlight_rows` :

```py
def highlight_rows(row):
    value = row.loc["status_type"]
    if value == "done":
        color = "#ffffff"
    elif value == "pending":
        color = "#474d51"
    else: # for any other value
        color = "000000"
    return [f'background-color: {color}' for _ in row]
```